# Finding the cost of flat object with mathematically defined shape

Tags: calculus, multiple-integral

I am given the following problem:

> You wish to manufacture a zinc object with the shape of the surface of the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ between the planes $z = 0$ and $x+y+z = 2$ (with $z \geq 0$). If the square meter of zinc cost $M$, what is the object's price?

My approach was to evaluate the volume of the object:

\begin{align*}
V = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{2-r\cos \theta - r \sin \theta}  \ r dzdrd\theta = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2} (2r - r^2 \cos \theta - r^2 \sin \theta ) \ drd\theta = \cdots = 8 \pi
\end{align*}

but I'm pretty sure that was useless, by the fact that the material cost is not related to the volume, but the surface area.

Can anyone point me into a direction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the order of integration of your volume so that it is
$$
V = \int_0^2 \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2-r\cos \theta - r \sin \theta} 
    r \,dz\,d\theta\,dr.
$$

Notice that this is like the shell method of integrating a volume of revolution, except that (because it is not a volume of revolution) the innermost integral has bounds that depend on $\theta.$
Despite this difference from the usual shell method, it is still the case that the outer integral is integrating over concentric "shells," each of which is some part of a cylinder.
You can write the integral as
$$
V = \int_0^2 A(r)\,dr
$$
where $A(r)$ is the area of the shell that has radius $r.$

Notice that the part of a cylinder whose area you are looking for
is also the outermost shell of this integral (the shell with radius $2$).
That should be a big hint about what integral would represent the area of that part of a cylinder.

---

But there is another wrinkle in this problem that one might miss.
If $\theta = 0$ or if $\theta = \frac\pi2,$ then
$2-r\cos \theta - r \sin \theta = 0.$
It turns out that $2-r\cos \theta - r \sin \theta < 0$ whenever
$0 < \theta < \frac\pi2.$

So there are actually two pieces of the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ between the planes $z = 0$ and $x + y + z = 2$: one above the plane $z = 0$ and one below that plane. If we just blindly integrated using the bound
$2-r\cos \theta - r \sin \theta$ over the entire interval
$\theta = 0$ to $\theta = 2\pi,$ we would count the piece below the plane as negative area.

I have never heard of negative zinc, so I suppose we are not allowed to do this. 
The reasonable alternatives are to negate the area below the plane $z = 0$ so that it is treated as positive area,
or leave out that part of the cylinder's surface entirely.
Since the problem statement says $z \geq 0,$ my interpretation would be that we are supposed to leave out the part of the cylinder below the plane $z = 0.$
In order to do that, the bounds of integration of $\theta$ have to be adjusted so that they do *not* include the interval $\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$.

Comment: Jesus that was brilliant. David I got $(2\pi + 1) M$ as an answer. Could you say if it matches yours?

Comment: I get something larger. To be honest, at first I missed the fact that part of the "shell" would be below the plane $z = 0$ and I thought the answer would simply be $2(2\pi r)M = 8\pi M,$ but it turned out to be even greater than that.

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to consider the change of coordinates by rotating the $xy$-plane by $45^\circ$ as:
$$u = x+y,\; v=x-y.$$
Then the top surface of the cylinder is described by the simple equation $z=2-u$ and you can calculate the elliptical surface area in terms of principle axes.

I hope, this is helpful.

Comment: I see. But would you say that the top and bottom are part of the object? Or should we just consider the side area?

Comment: for me, the task seemed to suggest a closed object, but depending on the context it may as well be only the cylindrical surface. But in any case, you can now calculate the surface area in the same manner as you did with the volume in cylindrical coordinates

Comment: in fact, the problem is very simple if you omit the elliptical surface. In these rotated coordinates, the cylinder is described by $u^2+v^2=1/2$ and the top cuts parallel to the v-axis exactly symmetrical in u. So the cylindrical surface is unchanged by the declination of the top plane

Comment: I am getting $(2\pi +1) M$ as an answer. Does it match yours? I am not particularly confident here.

Comment: The cylinder's side surface area is the same as for a standard right cylinder of height 2 (because it cuts the z-axis at z=2) and radius 2, so it should have a surface area of $2\cdot\pi\cdot 2^2=8\pi$. Only the area of the top face is slightly more complicated, but it gives $\pi\cdot\sqrt{2}$ square meters.

Comment: sorry, I meant to write $4\pi$ as the surface area of the sides, not the volume